# JSON-Path only returns single character instead of full value

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have a problem selecting the full value from a specific filter-selection.

Input JSON (from github-api response):

```
[
  {
    "name": "V2.X.X",
    "prerelease": true
  },
  {
    "name": "2.0.0",
    "prerelease": false
  },
  {
    "name": "1.9.0",
    "prerelease": false
  }
]
```

JSON-Path:

```
$.[?(@.prerelease==false)].name
```

Result:

```
[
  "2.0.0",
  "1.9.0"
]
```

I only need the first entry (**"2.0.0"**), so I tried this:

JSON-Path:

```
$.[?(@.prerelease==false)].name[0]
```

But result is:

```
[
  "2",
  "1"
]
```

**Any idea how to select the full first entry?**

I tested the JSONPatch on https://jsonpath.com/

BR

apiMan

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem with jsonpath I'm afraid.

See here: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/272 and https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/375

Unfortunately this doesn't look like it's going away any time soon - the issue was raised 2.5 years ago. What is annoying is that `$.[?(@.prerelease==false)].name[0]` used to work in version 0.9.1 of jsonpath and was then removed at some point.

The current workaround suggested is to read the items of your filtered expression into an in-memory collection and select the first one as you return it.

At any rate, you are not the first person to experience this problem, see:

- [How to get the first element when filter in jsonpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41529564/how-to-get-the-first-element-when-filter-in-jsonpath)
- [extracting single element from jsonpath array after query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768925/extracting-single-element-from-jsonpath-array-after-query)
- [Get specific object from JSONPath array result after predicate is applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572081/get-specific-object-from-jsonpath-array-result-after-predicate-is-applied)
- [Pick the 1st filtered result in JSONPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322086/pick-the-1st-filtered-result-in-jsonpath)

Comment: Thx, a lot for your detailed answers!
Unfortunately most of the discussed solutions use manipulation via java.
But I need a single JSONPath Expression, because I want to use shields.io for dynamicla creating badges-icons.
See https://shields.io/#dynamic-badge

Comment: NP - If you can get hold of a parser for v0.9.1 of the standard, you could use that.